# Create and query relations in Realm for React-Native app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongodb, react-native, realm

I am learning react-native and following [Realm tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/install/) on MongoDB docs, but I receive errors trying to create relationships in Realm.

I have a User and PokemonCard schemas.

- User can have multiple PokemonCards.
- PokemonCard can have only one User.

I am having trouble creating and querying those relationships.

When trying to create:

```
realm.write(() => {
  realm.create(PokemonCard, {
    title,
    description,
    user,
  });
});
```

How I get user:
`const user = useObject(User, userId);`

Error:
`No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 4, '(type: string, properties: Unmanaged<unknown, never>, mode?: UpdateMode.Never): Object<unknown, never>', gave the following error. Argument of type 'typeof PokemonCard' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Overload 2 of 4, '(type: new (...arg: any[]) => PokemonCard, properties: Unmanaged<PokemonCard, never>, mode?: UpdateMode.Never): PokemonCard', gave the following error. Type 'List<ObjectId>' is missing the following properties from type '(ObjectId | Unmanaged<ObjectId, never>)[]': reverse, sort, fill, copyWithints(2769)`

Schemas:

```
// To use a class as a Realm object type in Typescript with the `@realm/babel-plugin` plugin,
// simply define the properties on the class with the correct type and the plugin will convert
// it to a Realm schema automatically.

export class User extends Realm.Object<User> {
  _id: BSON.ObjectId = new BSON.ObjectId();
  name!: string;
  pokemonCards: Realm.List<PokemonCard>;
  pokemonCardIds: Realm.List<BSON.ObjectId>;
  createdAt: Date = new Date();
  static primaryKey = "_id";
}

export class PokemonCard extends Realm.Object<PokemonCard> {
  _id: BSON.ObjectId = new BSON.ObjectId();
  title!: string;
  description: string;
  user!: Realm.Results<User>;
  userId: BSON.ObjectId;
  createdAt: Date = new Date();
  static primaryKey = "_id";
}
```

package.json

````
  "dependencies": {
    "@realm/react": "^0.5.1",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "realm": "11.10.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.22.5",
    "@realm/babel-plugin": "^0.1.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.13",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },```


Workaround: 
I created `userId` and `pokemonCardIds` fields to pass not the whole object, but just ids and I later find needed objects by those fields, but I would like to learn the proper way of handling relationships in Realm.
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your User class has a `List` of `PokemonCard` objects; there may be no reason to also store the user objectID as that can be obtained from the objects in that List. Secondly, I would suggest defining an [Inverse Relationship](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/model-data/relationships-and-embedded-objects/#define-inverse-relationship-properties) which will automatically create a link from the PokemonCard back to the user to navigate the object graph inversely. That would also eliminate the need for the `userId`. This `user!: Realm.Results<User>;` is not valid.